# Is it possible to make MS Javascript Windows store App in visual studio 2012 as a web application that runs over the internet?

Tags: windows-8, cross-browser, visual-studio-2012, cross-platform, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to make an app in Javascript Windows store app (hosted on Windows 8) like ASP.Net or ASP MVC that works the same way as they do over the internet for different OSs and Browsers?

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? Are you asking:
a) Can you write an Windows Store WWA JavaScript app and run in on chrome?
b) Can you deliver the parts of your application live over the internet, rather than through the store, so you can update the app "instantly"?
c) Other?

Comment: I want to write a client server application just like formal ASP.Net Web application through IIS and windows webApplicationServer BUT I want to write it IN (Windows Store Javascript) rather than ASP.Net WebForms. Is it possible or (Windows Store Javascript) renders only localy on client machin? tnx D.H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinJS can only be used in a windows store application on the client. In certain situations, I can used in code delivered to the client via the server.

However running on the server as the server side script technology isn't possible today.

That stated there's nothing stoping you from trying to run the code in a node.js style environment, merely by picking up the js files and seeing where you get.